# How to make the ajax updater update all element with the class mydivclass with prototype js?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

With Prototype Js Ajax.updater, I would like to update EVERY div with a specific CLASS but when i do, it does not work for classes.

Element 1

Element 2

```
function mettreajour(span_id, url_traitement, nos_parametres)
    {

    var ajax = new Ajax.Updater ({success:span_id}, url_traitement, {method:'post', parameters: nos_parametres, evalScripts: true}  );

    }
```

even when i do

```
mettreajour('.mydivclass', 'index.php', &ok=yes);
```

it does not work.

How to make the ajax updater update all element with the class  `mydivclass`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on this is quite clear:

http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/

The `Ajax.Updater` will make a request, and replace the `innerHTML` of whichever element you identify by its ID with the results of that request. It's a one-trick pony, in other words.

If you want to build your own method to do this, there's two things to do. First, use the less-specialized `Ajax.Request` to fetch the data, then use the "double-dollar" `$$()` method to find the elements you would like to update. `$$()` always returns an array of elements (or an empty array, if nothing on the page matches the selector). You can iterate over that array using the Enumerable method each(), or you can use the special case `invoke()` (Prototype 1.7 and up) to call the same method for each element in the Enumerable.

```
new Ajax.Request('/your/url', {
  onSuccess: function(response) {
    $$('.some-class').invoke('update', response.responseText);
  }
});
```

or

```
new Ajax.Request('/your/url', {
  onSuccess: function(response) {
    $$('.some-class').each(function(elm){
      elm.update(response.responseText);
    });
  }
});
```